# Codeigniter navbar categories staying on default controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I can view dynamic categories when viewing my home (default controller) but when i click register or login button the categories fail; as it seems the foreach doesn't work on those pages, i'll explain with my code.

Controller (home.php - default controller)

```
 public function index()
       {    
    $data['mcats'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    foreach($data['mcats'] as $key => $val){
        $subcats = $this->Categories_model->get_categoriesSub($val['cid']);
        if($subcats){
            $data['scats'][$val['cid']] = $subcats;
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

View (navigation.php)

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">   
    <?php
      foreach($mcats as $key =>$val) {
        ?>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<?=$val['cid'];?>"><?=$val['category'];?></a>
        </li>
        <?php
      } ?>
</ul>
```

I need someway of making the index function within my home controller work no matter if i'm on the home page or register etc,

I have tried adding more views in the home controller:

$this->load->view('register', $data)

But this just makes in one dimensional.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have managed to work out how to do this, so for anyone else who was stuck this is what i did.

Home Controller

I kept the below function which gets the categories.

```
public function index()
{   
    $data['mcats'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    foreach($data['mcats'] as $key => $val){
        $subcats = $this->Categories_model->get_categoriesSub($val['cid']);
        if($subcats){
            $data['scats'][$val['cid']] = $subcats;
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

I copied the index function about and added it into my Auth.php controller which has two functions - register and login. I added the index function at the step where i load the register and login views.

Auth.php controller - Register function

```
public function register()
    $data['mcats'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    foreach($data['mcats'] as $key => $val){
    $subcats = $this->Categories_model->get_categoriesSub($val['cid']);
        if($subcats){
            $data['scats'][$val['cid']] = $subcats;
        }
    }   
    $this->load->view('register', $data);
}
```

Auth.php controller - Loginfunction

```
public function login()
    $data['mcats'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    foreach($data['mcats'] as $key => $val){
    $subcats = $this->Categories_model->get_categoriesSub($val['cid']);
        if($subcats){
            $data['scats'][$val['cid']] = $subcats;
        }
    }   
    $this->load->view('login', $data);
}
```

This now allows the function to work when loading login or register.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using constructor, and define the variables which need to be used in multiple functions.

```
public function __construct(){

   //load the model.
   $this->load->model('Categories_model', 'Categories_model');

   $this->data['mcats'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
   foreach($this->data['mcats'] as $key => $val){

      $subcats = $this->Categories_model->get_categoriesSub($val['cid']);
      if($subcats){
         $this->data['scats'][$val['cid']] = $subcats;
      }
   }   
}

public function index()
    $this->load->view('home', $this->data);
}

public function register()
    $this->load->view('register', $this->data);
}

public function login()
    $this->load->view('login', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: Which controller would you put this in?

Comment: Your default controller from where your using all 3(index, register, login) functions

Comment: I added like you suggested, and remove the lines from the individual functions within the other controllers and when i ran the code it couldn't find my model. I have tried manually loading the model but it makes no difference; plus i have autoloaded it.

Comment: id missed off the construct function parent::__construct(), so now the home controller loads the home view. When i select the other views - login or register, it can't see the details within the construct of the home controller.. So seems like my answer i wrote first is the only way I can get it to work.

Comment: I had code to load a model in constructor, can you please check it.